# Apache not reading "If" part of the code

Tags: php, if-statement, server

This is probably not just me. My apache server isn't reading the "if" portion of my code. I have `

```
     <div id="toolbar">
         <? if(isset($_SESSION["steamname"]))
            {
                    <a class="button-logout" href="steamauth/logout.php">Log Out</a> 

                }
            else
                {
                    <a class="button-login" href="steamauth/login_steam.php">Log In</a>

                }
        ?>
    </div>`
```

In my index.php but in google chrome I get

```
<!--?   if(isset($_SESSION["steamname"]))
            {
                    <a class="button-logout" href="steamauth/logout.php"-->
```

and the other bottom half gets read. I doubt that php is missing on my machine as the other php portions of my code works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<?php
```

instead of

```
<?
```

sometimes you can't use short tags...you can edit the option values in php.ini file.